# How to validate a select tag in struts 2 framework

Tags: validation, struts2

I am a newbie into programming and i am currently employed as a junior programmer.
I am currently having some problems validating the select tags in one of my forms.
What i actually trying to do is to ensure that one item is selected before the user submits the form .

In the form i have;

```
<s:select list="assessmentTypes" headerKey="0" headerValue=" -- Select One --"
          listKey="id" value="name" listValue="name" key="course.assessmenttype"
          name="assessmenttype.id"/>
```

I have some knowledge of validation but not to sure how to do it for the select list.

I tried using a normal validation with strings but i don't think it is required in this case. for example;

```
<field name="course.assessmenttype">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please Select a value</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

all help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an int validator with a min value set. Since you want any value greater than 0.

```
     <field name="course.assessmenttype">
          <field-validator type="int">
              <param name="min">1</param>
              <message>Please Select a value to continue</message>
          </field-validator>
      </field>
```

Comment: Hey,
I tried the Suggestion, but still ending with failures.

    Object of class [com.sbcstnt.core.model.AssessmentType] with identifier [0]: not found 

anymore ideas, Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the field is being validated? Check the name of the field against the field name in the validation xml file to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Set headerKey="0" to headerKey=""

```
<field name="course.assessmenttype">
          <field-validator type="requiredstring">
              <param name="trim">true</param>
              <message>Please Select a value to continue</message>
          </field-validator>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="course.assessmenttype">  
           <field-validator type="regex">  
       <param name="expression">assessmentTypes</param>  
       <message>Select a value to continue</message>  
     </field-validator>  
      </field> 
instead of assessmentTypes, you can directly mention the dropdown list values. Make sure that your validator XML file is in the format <ActionClassname>-validation.xml,which should be in the same package as Action class
```