# How to validate dynamic radio buttons using struts2 validation.xml

Tags: validation, struts2, annotations

I have some radio buttons that are generated dynamically, I want to validate these fields. How do I do it in validation.xml(Struts2)?

Can I do this using annotations? Not sure how to though..

Comment: can you provide some code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequiredFieldValidator` with the specific property in the bean.

these links might help you.

[struts-2-validation-using-annotations](http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/05/10/struts-2-validation-using-annotations/)

[how-to-validate-a-select-tag-in-struts-2-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758088/how-to-validate-a-select-tag-in-struts-2-framework)

Comment: Hmmm actually I hit a server with some personal info and i get a set of questions and their corresponing choices. I placed the choices in the radio button grp. and the names are dynamic, say like question_i where i varies from 0-4 or more. Also I do not have any info on how many choices would be returned, but I have to make sure the user answers all qns. Any idea?

Comment: why dont you use javascript to verify it? i mean, if you know the id of the radio buttons then iterate over them and check if any one of them is selected or not. This JS method can be called before every next question i.e. when users opts to go to next question.

Comment: [this link might be helpful to you](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/updating_a_list_of_domain_entities)